# чтение названия файла на русском языке

Tags: php

Всем привет. Читаю содержимое директории вот так:

```
  $img_a = scandir($dir);
  var_dump($img_a);
```

и естественно вижу следующее `�����������.jpg`.

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: почту естественно ? у меня вот например все нормально отображается

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan, вы на каком сервере пробовали? может это от настроек зависит? я на openserver проверяю

Comment: Попробуйте кодировку файла где вы редактируете код ставить в `utf-8 без бом`.Если не поможет то в начале кода пропишите `header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8')`.Если и это не поможет то будем думать дальше.Я на `xampp` пробовал локально.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan, попробовал, не помогает.

Comment: есть несколько вариантов, почему появляется баг. нужно проверять кодировку html-страницы - раз, нужно проверить кодировку имени файла на диске - два, нужно проверить charset html-страницы.

Comment: попробуйте [это](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.rawurlencode.php), мне помогло

Comment: @DNS Да в принципе может сработать

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan, была та же проблемма... Решил именно так

Comment: Ситуация без изменений, в настройках openserver поставил кодировку сервера по умолчанию, стало все нормально. строка header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8') в начале скрипта выводит снова кракозябры. допишу скрипт, буду тестить на ubuntu, посмотрим что будет там.

Comment: Укажите в браузере кодировку utf-8